# Conditions for a probability density to be bounded

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

I'm having problem showing that when a probability density function $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, its first derivative $f'$ is absolutely continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and second derivative satisfies $\int (f''(x))^2 < \infty$, then $f$ must be bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm also not sure why the following argument doesn't work given that there exist continuous density functions that are not $L_2$:

Since $\int f(x) dx = 1$, it must be that $f$ is bounded almost everywhere and hence bounded everywhere, say by $B>0$, when $f$ is continuous. Then, $\|f\|_{2}^2 = \int (f(x))^2 dx \leq B \int f(x) dx = B$ so that $f \in L_2(\mathbb{R})$ as long as it is assumed continuous.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $|f| \leq M$ almost everywhere then $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x$ because $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Right, it suffices to show the statment for almost every $x$. Thanks.

Comment: Concerning the argument you presented, I do not think $\int f(x) dx = 1$ yields boundendess of $f$, even if $f$ is assumed to be continuous. Think of a function which takes the value $n$ on an interval $A_n$ of length $n^{-3}$. Clearly it is possible to construct a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$ with this property for disjoint sets $A_n$, which is positive and integrable.